# HtmlTargetElementAttribute equivalent for Razor Components?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.0

Is there a way to specify a target element for a Razor component, similar to how HtmlTargetElement was used for Tag Helpers?

```
@inherits NavigationBase

<ul class="@Class">
    @foreach (INavigation nav in RazorManager.Navigations[Group])
    {
        <li>
            <a href="@nav.Route">@nav.Text</a>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Current usage:

```
<Navigation group="Main" class="nav navbar-nav" />
```

Desired usage:

```
<navigation group="Main" class="nav navbar-nav">
```

With tag helpers, was as simple as:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("navigation", TagStructure = TagStructure.WithoutEndTag)]
```